# Express and Mongoose-property is not being saved

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

TL;DR: I'm trying to save a new object, one of the fields is not saving, others save fine.

I've got a Mongoose schema with a property called superPlotId:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const GeoJSON = require('mongoose-geojson-schema');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const plotSchema = new Schema(
    {
        ...fields...
        superPlotId: String,
        ...more fields
    },
    { strict: false },
    { bufferCommands: false }
);

//create model class
const ModelClass = mongoose.model('plot', plotSchema);

//export model
module.exports = ModelClass;
```

I'm trying to save a new object fitting this schema with Express, like this:

```
exports.newPlot = async (req, res, next) => {
    const {
        ...a bunch of fields...
        superPlotId
    } = req.body.props;
    const plot = new Plot({
        ...a bunch of fields...
        superPlotId
    });
    console.log(('new plot:', JSON.stringify(plot)));
    try {
        const newPlot = await plot.save();
        res.json(newPlot);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("couldn't save new plot", JSON.stringify(e));
        return res.status(422).send({ error: { message: e, resend: true } });
    }
};
```

I know that a properly formatted object is hitting the endpoint, because the console.log above shows it:

```
{...bunch of fields..."superPlotId":"5a9e9f9f0f8a8026005fe1e7"}
```

And yet the plot appears in my database without the superPlotId field.

Anyone know what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
try {
    let plot = new Plot();
    plot = Object.assign(plot, req.body.props);
    const newPlot = await plot.save();
    res.json(newPlot);
} catch (e) {
    console.log("couldn't save new plot", JSON.stringify(e));
    return res.status(422).send({
        error: {
            message: e,
            resend: true
        }
    });
}
```